# Register-ScheduledTask : No mapping betwen account names and security IDs was done

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to run this script remotely and I keep receiving the following error:

```
Register-ScheduledTask : No mapping between account names and security IDs was
done.
(42,4):UserId:
At C:\TempSQL\FullSQLBackupInstaller.ps1:39 char:13
+             Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'crebackup' -InputObject ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/.
   ..S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070534,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Here is the script:

```
function windowsTask {
$taskName = "crebackup"
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName}
if($taskExists) {
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "crebackup"}
else {
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\POSNation\SQLBackup\SQLBackup.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\POSNation\SQLBackup\"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 3am
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'crebackup' -InputObject $Task -User $env:UserName
}
#$taskName = "crebackup"
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName
}
```

Comment: How are you running the function remotely?

Comment: Utilizing screenconnect we open a rdp session backstage which has a admin powershell running.

Comment: @Scepticalist ^^

Comment: Are logged in as local admin or a domain account?

Comment: @Scepticalist logged in as the local admin

Comment: Try specifying the local computer domain for the user object when creeating the task e.g. -User computername\username

Comment: How about `[Environment]::UserName` instead `$env:UserName` ?

Answer (score 0):

try one of these lines. both should set the full username properly.

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'crebackup' -InputObject $Task -User "$Env:USERDOMAIN\$ENV:USERNAME"
```

or

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'crebackup' -InputObject $Task -User (whoami)
```